# pipe output of a binary to linux commands

Tags: javascript, linux, bash

I have a javascript binary that builds some of my files. I wrote a bash script that automates building my project using the javascript binary and I want to catch the errors that the javascript binary will output.

```
my-build-script.js path/to/file | echo
```

The issue with this is that my-build-script.js will think " | echo" is an argument and throws some errors. Is there a way to pipe the output of my javascript file to a linux command?

Comment: If that's a `bash` script, then no, your script will not think that `| echo` is part of the argument list; it won't be told about that part of the command line at all.

Comment: Also, a JavaScript program isn't really a "binary". That term is usually reserved for the results of compiling a C or C++ program (or other similar language).

Comment: ALso also, `| echo` doesn't really do anything because the `echo` builtin doesn't read standard input.

Comment: isn't your script already writing to `stdout` ? (or are you looking for redirecting **only** `stderr`)